# Адаптивность для длинного текста в таблице

Tags: веб-программирование, html5, css3, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Такой вопрос, как решить проблему с адаптивностью большого текста в таблице.

Не знаю разрешено ли давать ссылку на свой проект,

http://mvcdiplom.azurewebsites.net/Descriptions/Index

Вся проблема отображена на странице, если уменьшать разрешение, то текст за рамки уходит

Интересует, можно ли каким-нибудь образом это исправить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте свойство `overflow` чтобы добавить полосы прокрутки. Значание `auto` добавляет полосы прокрутки только при необходимости.

```
<div class="panel-heading panel-primary">
    <h2 align="center">Список описаний</h2>
</div>

<div style="overflow: auto;" class="panel-body"> <!-- overflow -->

    <table  class="table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered">
```